# Explicit constructor with all default arguments can't be called from another constructor of the same class

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

Why explicit constructor with all default arguments can't be called from another constructor of the same class?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>


 class A {
 public:
   explicit A(int a = 1, int b = 2) :
     a_(a),
     b_(b) {}

   A(std::string s)
     : A() {
       std::cout << s;
   }   

   int a_;
   int b_;
 };

 int main() {
   A a("!");
   std::cout << a.a_;
 }
```

g++ -v

gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

g++ -o out -std=c++11 main.cpp

Error: main.cpp:12:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’

Comment: I am using g++ version 4.8.2

Comment: [Cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a30ffe7de0fbb737), [same with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94158d1858fecd3f)

Comment: Works fine in g++ 4.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a gcc bug fixed in 4.9.0: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58255